# Pass custom props to Redux Form Field in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-form

I want to pass custom properties to my Redux-Form-Field. In the documentation it says:

> Any custom props passed to Field will be merged into the props object on the same level as the input and meta objects.

But passing a custom prop to the Field component will throw a compile error:

```
<Field
    name="E-Mail"
    component={MaterialTextField}
    myProp="Test"
/>
```

Property 'myProp' does not exist on type '(IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & ...

Inside the props attribute I can only add a predefined set of properties like placeholder or type. Passing another prop will throw this error:

```
<Field
    name="E-Mail"
    component={MaterialTextField}
    props = {{
        myProps: 'Test'
    }}
/>
```

Type '{ name: "E-Mail"; component: (props: any) => Element; props: { myProps: string; }; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & ...

Is there a possibility to pass custom props to the Field component in TypeScript?

Comment: you have `redux-form` and `react-redux-form` but those are actually two different frameworks. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: My bad, I am referring to redux-form.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some more experimenting on my side I found a solution to pass custom props:

```
<Field 
    name="myName"
    props={{
        type: 'text'
    }}
    component={myComponent}
    {...{
        myCustomProps1: 'myCustomProp1',
        myCustomProps2: 'myCustomProp2'
    }}
/>
```

In myComponent you have your custom props on the root level of your properties:

```
const myComponent = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.myCustomProp1 + " " props.myCustomProp2}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To pass **custom props** to `Field` component of **Redux Form**, you need to declare an **interface** of all the **props** you want to pass.

```
interface YourCustomProps {
    myProp1: string;
    myProp2: number;
}
```

Now, use `GenericField` from **Redux Form** to make `Field` as `YourCustomField` to which you will be able to pass `YourCustomProps`

```
import { Field, GenericField } from 'redux-form';

const YourCustomField = Field as new () => GenericField<YourCustomProps>;
```

Now you can pass **custom props** to `YourCustomField` as declared in the interface.

```
<YourCustomField
    myProp1="Hi"
    myProp2={123}
    component={MaterialTextField}
/>
```

This way you can pass anything as **custom props** such as react components as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Typescript user, so I'm not sure how the type definitions work, but I found [this thread about type definitions for Redux-form v6](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1211). In the end they link to [this repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/redux-form) which is supposed to have (if I understand it correctly) updated type definitions.

I guess an alternative would be to switch to vanilla JS for this specific functionality. Or maybe it would be possible to define a function that takes your custom prop and then returns a component ready to take the Redux form props and merge them.

**Edit**: I've tried to illustrate the basic idea of the last suggestion, a so-called HOC (Higher Order Component), in the included code below.

```js
const inputWithCustomFields = (customFields) => ComponentToGetExtraFields => (props) => {
 const mergedProps = {...props, ...customFields};
 return (<ComponentToGetExtraFields {...mergedProps} />);
};

const ComponentThatNeedsCustomStuff = ({myCustomField1, myCustomField2, ...rest}) => {
 console.log('doing stuff with the custom props',myCustomField1, myCustomField2);
 return (<div><h1>{myCustomField1 + myCustomField2}</h1><input {...rest} /></div>);
}

const Parent = () => {
  const myCustomFields = {
     myCustomField1: "Hello, ", 
     myCustomField2: "world!", 
     value: 'can\'t change me',
     onChange: () => { /* do nothing */ }
   };
  const MergedComponent  = inputWithCustomFields(myCustomFields)(ComponentThatNeedsCustomStuff);
  return (<div>
      <MergedComponent />
    </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17271977)

Comment: Fair enough. Can't do much about the the remaining links (too much code/text to copy etc.) but I've added a code example for one part that previously was just vaguely pointing at the contents of a link.